# Report correct location with carp inside Try::Tiny catch block

Tags: perl, try-catch, perl-module, error-reporting

I'm am using `carp` in a [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny) `catch` block, and it always reports the error from the wrong location. The documentation for `Try::Tiny` says that it adds itself to `%Carp::Internal` so that it doesn't appear in longer backtraces. But it still appears in the summary line. The documentation for [`Carp`](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp) says that adding a package name to `%Carp::CarpInternal` will remove the package from both the stack trace and the summary line. So I've done that, but the reported location is still incorrect. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
MyPackage::foo();

package MyPackage;
use Try::Tiny;
use Carp;
use vars qw(%Carp::CarpInternal);
$Carp::CarpInternal{'Try::Tiny'}++;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%Carp::CarpInternal;
print Dumper \%Carp::Internal;

sub foo {
    carp 'bar1';
    try{
        carp 'bar2'
    }catch {
        carp $_;
    }
}

1;
```

And here's what it prints:

```
bar1 at myFile.t line 1.
bar2 at myFile.t line 21.
$VAR1 = {
      'Try::Tiny' => 1,
      'warnings' => 1,
      'Carp' => 1
    };
$VAR1 = {
      'Try::Tiny' => 1,
      'Exporter::Heavy' => 1,
      'Exporter' => 1
    };
```

The two variables are what I expect them to be, but I want the errors to both be reported at line 1 of myFile.t. Does anyone know how to fix the error reporting location to be what I want?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you don't need to `use vars` for a fully-qualified variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experiment, this solution only works when the caller comes from a different file. Adding `Try::Tiny` to the `@CARP_NOT` variable for the package fixes in this case:

```
#first file
use MyPackage;
MyPackage::foo();

#second file
package MyPackage;
use Carp qw(carp cluck);
our @CARP_NOT = qw(Try::Tiny);
use Try::Tiny;

sub foo {
    carp 'bar1';
    cluck 'bar2';
    try{
        carp 'bar3'
    }catch {
        cluck $_;
    }
}
1;
```

It prints the following:

```
bar1 at myFile.t line 2.
bar2 at MyPackage.pm line 8.
        MyPackage::foo() called at myFile.t line 2
bar3 at myFile.t line 2.
```